# Exported contacts not visible in Android Enterprise on Android 10

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-enterprise

We export contacts to the address book by utilizing ContentProvider with ContactsContact.AUTHORITY (com.android.contacts).
This works flawless on regular installations and also on Android Enterprise below Android 10.

On Android 10 with Android Enterprise the contact export worker also runs successfully, no exception, no warning. The exported contacts are **not visible** in the contacts app though, on fresh test devices it shows "no contacts yet".
They exist and can be found by searching for them. They are also used to identify an incoming caller.

Any idea if we have to set a flag or do something else to make the contacts appear in the contacts app?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, since Android 11 this (rather exotic) issue seems to be fixed.

I filed a bug report with google, but in the five months they were not able to reproduce the issue as their support did not understand the difference between a work profile and a private profile.